# Using .pch file to include applcation files

Tags: ios

I just came to know that if we include anything in .pch file, we don't have to include later in other files. Now I am thinking of adding all of my files in it so that I don't have to include them in other files and create a mess at the start of each file. But I was thinking if this is a good practice? If not, why? And if good, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Hi Alex .. I'll take bad ideas for $1000"  :D

Aside from Oscar's answer, you will also subvert the build process.  As every file knows about and hence depends on every other file, then changing a single file will mean that all compilation units in the project will be forced to be built on every recompilation - rather than just building what has changed.

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely not a good practice, you should however definitely include the files that will be needed in all or most of the files, singletons and data models would be a good candidate for example.

The reason why this is a bad idea is cycling references, if you were to include all your files in that .pch file you will soon get some errors about cycling references.

Comment: And also: https://twitter.com/eridius/statuses/169603722454896640 though they are uncited. @eridius cites years of experience, which may or may not be good enough for you : https://twitter.com/eridius/statuses/172390795402428416