# including common header files in .pch file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am just wondering, is it good practice to include commonly/mostly used header files in .pch file?

e.g Most of files required below headers

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

So instead of each file should have, is it good practice to add those in .pch file?

.pch file

```
     #ifdef __OBJC__
     #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
     #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
     #import <MostlyUsed.h>
     #endif
```

I found some disadvantages of this,
1) Dependancies get hidden.
2) Source files can not be copied directly.

It will be great if you guys provide some inputs on this.

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540155/using-pch-file-to-include-applcation-files?rq=1

Comment: while i was completing the answer, you changed your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can do it.

Even it reduces compile time.

An Extract from [In Objective-C, importing same headers in every class make compile time longer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910065/in-objective-c-importing-same-headers-in-every-class-make-compile-time-longer)

> In general, newly-generated iOS projects come with this functionality,
>   which is called a precompiled header or prefix header, and is a file
>   that has the extension .pch.
>
> You can throw all the headers you want in there and Xcode will
>   pre-compile it before it builds anything else, and use it to compile
>   the other compilation units in your project (e.g. .m files).
>
> Using a precompiled header may or may not increase compile time; in
>   general, it reduces compile time, as long as you have a lot of common
>   headers and/or a lot of source files.
>
> However, it's not necessarily good practice to treat the pre-compiled
>   header like a big dumping ground, as your compilation units can form
>   implicit dependencies on all sorts of stuff when you may want to
>   enforce loose coupling between components.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly a good practice as it reduces compile time and code is lot more manageable by doing so.