# Is it a good or bad thing to import all classes in app-prefix.pch

Tags: ios, objective-c

If abusing _***prefix.pch*** for global imports will only affect the compile time, then according to my thinking it will not have any performance overhead while the app is running. The question is what's the real price for importing all project classes in the ***app-prefix.pch*** file.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540155/using-pch-file-to-include-applcation-files?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Includes don't have an impact on runtime at all, no matter where you make them. However, when you just include everything in the pre-compiled header, your compile time will skyrocket because your whole code has to be recompiled every time one of the headers changes.

Comment: Does it mean it's OK to have all the system framework includes in the .pch file?

Comment: @BlackRider Yes, that's okay.

Comment: @JustSid according to your answer, it's totally not ok to have every header file compiled again on any change.

Comment: @deadlock Can you rephrase that? Sorry, I don't quite get it, header files aren't compiled at all.

Answer (score 3):

Precompiled prefix headers are only there to speed up compilation time. Having **everything** in there defeats their purpose because you need to recompile everything every time one of your header files changes.

Furthermore, if someone looks at your code and there are no `#imports` they won't see the dependencies of the code they are looking at. It's also impossible to just extract a class from your project as it depends on the prefix header.

Have a look at Jon Reid's [4 Ways Precompiled Headers Cripple Your Code](http://qualitycoding.org/precompiled-headers/) for more information.